# Failed to add Push Notification Plugin into cordova

Tags: cordova, push-notification

I have just created a testing cordova project and now am trying to add a simple Push Notification plugin (https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin) into my project.

I followed its instruction and typed this :

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin.git
```

But immediately, the command line failed with this error message:

```
F:\Workplace\pushnotification\pushnotification>cordova plugin add https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin.git
Fetching plugin "https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin.git" via git clone
Error: Command failed: fatal: could not create work tree dir 'C:\Users\FRANV_~1\AppData\Local\Temp\plugman\git\1398870928641'.: No such file or directory

    at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:637:15)
    at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:743:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (child_process.js:956:11)
    at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at Pipe.close (net.js:465:12)
```

I just did the updating of my Tortoise GitHub, but it didn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems there is a bug in git source dependencies on Windows.

Try to create the directory manually :

```
mkdir C:\Users\FRANV_~1\AppData\Local\Temp\plugman\git\1398870928641
```

Then :

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin.git
```

Comment: Hi Robin, thanks. It works now. I just don't like the git bug. How can I inform them to fix this issue?(I also wonder how could git team make this obvious mistake(sorry if it's a mistake/bug)).

Comment: This issue has already been opened in the Scale repo, but not resolved yet.  https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/895

Comment: Hi Robin, could you please provide the issue (tracking) url/link?

Comment: @RobinCominotto it is not working when i try to run a command it always generate new name of directory any other solution?